# Typescript reorder array of objects by object.id when type of object/id is generic

Tags: typescript

I would like to write a function which reorders an array of either NumberId objects or array of StringId Objects by their id.

This is my approach so far

```
class NumberId {
  id: number,
  name: string
}

class StringId {
  id: string,
  name: string
}

class IdClass = StringId | NumberId

function reorder<T extends IdClass>(foos: T[], ids: T["id"][]): T[]{
  type MapType = {[key in T["id"]]: T}

  const map: MapType = {}
  foos.forEach((f) => {
    map[f.id] = f;
  })
  return ids.map((id => map[id])
}
```

But I am getting the error `Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'MapType'` on the assignment `const map: MapType = {}`.

---

Edit:

When I try `const map: MapType = {} as MapType` I get the folowing problem on `map[f.id] =f`:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string | number' can't be used to index type 'MapType'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'MapType'.
```

Comment: `const map = {} as MapType;` might be more appropriate.

Comment: @caTS I've updated my question with the problem that arises when I try this